# Setting up GraphQL mock server for Relay Modern

Tags: mocking, graphql, relay, react-apollo

I am attempting to set up a GraphQL mockServer from 'gralphql-tools' in a Relay-Modern app but am getting this error:

```
parser.js:152 Uncaught 
GraphQLError {message: "Syntax Error GraphQL (1:1) Unexpected Name "data"↵…GVUeXBlIHsKICBVUAogIERPV04KICBDQU5DRUwKfQo=↵   ^↵", locations: Array(1), path: undefined, stack: "GraphQLError↵    at syntaxError (http://localhost:…tp://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33240:27)", nodes: undefined…}
locations
:
Array(1)
message
:
"Syntax Error GraphQL (1:1) Unexpected Name "data"↵↵1:
```

I'm attempting to implement the strategy outlined in http://graphql.org/blog/mocking-with-graphql/ with the relay-modern-hello-world [repo](https://github.com/apollographql/relay-modern-hello-world).

I've basically tried to replace the fetchQuery() to replace the post request to the API included in the example:

```
function fetchQuery() {
    mockServer(schema, {
        Int: () => 6,
        Float: () => 22.1,
        String: () => 'Hello',
    });

    const appQuery = `
        query AppFeedQuery {
            feed (type: NEW, limit: 5) {
                ...Feed
            }
        }
    `;

    return mockServer.query(appQuery);
}

// Create a network layer from the fetch function
const network = Network.create(fetchQuery);

const source = new RecordSource();
const store = new Store(source);
```

My attempt can be found at https://github.com/sdee/relay-modern-hello-world

I'd appreciate any ideas. I'm new to Relay and GraphQL. Thanks!